# Printing a 1" scale from 2.8.2 Print Composer

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, scale

I'm working on a small-scale site survey in qGIS, and for engineering purposes I need to print physical copies of the map that can be used with an engineering ruler.

Basically, I need a way to print a scale bar that has intervals that will actually be 1". The map is at 1":500", and I'm using NAD83 CA State Plane V (ft). For the life of me I can't find an option that lets me dictate the size of the scale bar on a paper map. I am printing as a raster, rather than scaling to fit the page, but still no luck.

I'm having the issue that's detailed [here](https://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/gis-tips-arcgis-scalebar-prints-incorrect-scale/) but that solution is for ArcMap Layout, and I need to use QGIS Print Composer.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Units** section of the scale bar properties, set it to feet.

**Label Unit Multiplier** should be set to 0.083333 as well. This is from 1/12.

**Label For Units** can also be changed to *in*

Then under the **Segments** portion set the **Fixed Width** to however many feet are in 500".

Not sure how precise you need the scale bar units to be, but the calculator from 500/12 = 41.666666666666666666666666666667

So the fixed width would be something in that range, like 41.66667 (rounded).

[image: 11 inch scale bar across an 8.5x11" paper]

The image above shows 1" increments which are 500" and to test, has 11 1" segments that fit perfectly across an 11" piece of paper.